How do I make a stacked bar chart created from a Pivot table arranged from descending order (largest - smallest) in Excel?
I am creating a dashboard and have added a stacked bar chart that totals up to 100 % of the inputs in the production cycle. The stacked bar chart was created using a data in a Pivot table. The input values are monetary, and the input with the largest value make up the largest % share of the bar chart's bars.
I have been struggling with getting the bar chart arrange in an descending order, meaning the largest share being at the bottom and the next largest coming after etc.
Does anyone know how to achieve this?
I tried using Chatgpt to achieve this, but when I try to arrange the Pivot table, I cannot arrange the entire row, just a column.
